# Count capital letters in String

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i count Capital letters with a MySQL-query?
I'm trying it at the moment with

```
COUNT(IF(MATCH(post_text) AGAINST('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'),1,NULL))
```

But this is giving me an Error saying:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U' at line 4
```

I guess, I'm not allowed not use lists in the AGAINST clauses which sucks

So, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: try: `COUNT(IF(MATCH(post_text) AGAINST('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z'),1,NULL))`

Comment: but this is going to count the occurence of 'A,B,C[...],Z'

Comment: i think mysql will ignore words shorter than three characters when doing fulltext search (MATCH AGAINST)

Comment: @Harry Joy: count('ABCABCABC',array('A,'B,'C')) => 9; count('ABCABCABC',array('A,B,C')) => 0; I hope you see the difference in my pseudocode example ...

Comment: @Seshiro: okay I got it.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to count capital letters with an SQL query if I may ask? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION cnt_up_case(str VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
BEGIN

  SET @cnt = 0;
  SET @len = length(str);
  SET @i = 1;

  WHILE @i <= @len
  DO
    SET @c = substring(str, @i, 1);
    IF ascii(@c) > 64 AND ascii(@c) < 91 THEN
      SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    END IF;

    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN @cnt;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Example:

```
SET @Param1 = 'AbCdE';
SET @ResultValue = cnt_up_case(@Param1);
SELECT @ResultValue;
--------------
3
```

Comment: #1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable); This is going to be the thing i wanted

Comment: These options are default; but they can be declared. I edited code.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL RETURNS VARCHAR(255) BEGIN SET @cnt = 0; ' at line 2; meh, sorry for the stress

Comment: Oh, I inserted those options in the wrong place. They should be placed after RETURNS clause.

Answer (score 4):

If your table has one column(columnname) and has these values:

- Aaaaaa
- AAAAaa
- AAAAAA

You get the Capital count back per value by using the following query:

```
SELECT columnname,(length(columnname)  - length( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(naam,'Z','') ,'Y','') ,'X','') ,'W','') ,'V','') ,'U','') ,'T','') ,'S','') ,'R','') ,'Q','') ,'P','') ,'O','') ,'N','') ,'M','') ,'L','') ,'K','') ,'J','') ,'I','') ,'H','') ,'G','') ,'F','') ,'E','') ,'D','') ,'C','') ,'B','') ,'A','') ) )  FROM column
```

Comment: Creative solution!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a first ' before the character A, and one after Z.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not missing in the original code so this doesn't seem to be the error

Comment: Ahh, okay, it's going to be a pretty difficult one to solve without having the Match function.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - are you trying with a SELECT statement at the beginning?

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(MATCH(post_text) AGAINST('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z'),1,NULL))
```

Comment: No, it's a calculation im trying to substract the count from a number so it's not a select; It has a sligt bigger context so i'll update

Comment: Just thought - I think you need to do the list like 'A B C' [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but it is very dirty..

You can remove capital letters from `post_text` and then compare its length to the oryginal `post_text` length:

```
COUNT(post_text) - COUNT( REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(post_text, 'D', ''), 'C', ''), 'B', ''), 'A', '') )
```

I do not know if you want to use it and I do not want to convince you about it but it is one of the possibilities.