# Regex - SQL - Query for finding all words that contain at-least 3 capital letters (Does not have to be in order)

Tags: sql, vertica

I want to basically catch all of the words that contain at-least 3 capital letters anywhere throughout the word.

Example words that I am trying to catch:

```
sksDDKDeS4Ataow,
dS19DsA2NTbpctK
```

My bad regex:
    regexp_like(word, '[A-Z]{1,4}?+[a-z]{1,16}+[A-Z]{1,4}?+[a-z]{1,16}+[A-Z]{1,4}?')

Comment: Presumably you will need `REGEXP_LIKE`

Comment: I would look at this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661692/count-capital-letters-in-string

Answer (score 2):

Try this one - it matches where the word says they should match ...

```
WITH
words(word) AS (
          SELECT 'noMatch'
UNION ALL SELECT 'onlYtwoNomatch'
UNION ALL SELECT 'thrEECapsmatch'
UNION ALL SELECT 'ThReeCapsmatch'
UNION ALL SELECT 'FourMatcHToo'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM words
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(word,'([A-Z]\w*){3}')
;
```